# Can't see to get layout right (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

First, here's my XAML markup (ModifySpDefaultValues.xaml):

```
<Page x:Class="EMS_WPF_Test.ModifySpDefaultValues"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EMS_WPF_Test"
  mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="360" Title="ModifyPvDefaultValues" Style="{DynamicResource Form}" d:DesignHeight="360" MinHeight="360" MinWidth="360">
<ScrollViewer Margin="10" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DockPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <Label Content="Min/max" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Minimum allowed sp:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Maximum allowed sp:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Alarm values" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Period:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Min Pv:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Max Pv:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Local setpoint" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Default setpoint:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="External setpoint" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Sp addition:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="Default manual setpoint:" Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label x:Name="GoBack" Content="Back" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}" MouseLeftButtonUp="GoBack_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
            <Label Content="What's this?" Style="{DynamicResource Hyperlink}"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <Label Style="{DynamicResource Label}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
            <TextBox Style="{DynamicResource TextBox}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

XAML for window (loads the page above):

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="EMS_WPF_Test.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EMS_WPF_Test"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Modify device" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="680" Height="300" Width="680" Source="ModifySpDefaultValues.xaml" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ShowsNavigationUI="False">
```

Styles:

```
<Application x:Class="Test.App"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <!-- Header text style -->
    <Style x:Key="Hyperlink">
        <Setter Property="Label.Margin" Value="0,0,25,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HotTrackBrushKey}}"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="OperationMethodBox">
        <Setter Property="Label.Margin" Value="0,0,25,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="ComboBox.Width" Value="300"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Label.Margin" Value="0,0,25,0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="TextBox.MinWidth" Value="50"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Height" Value="20"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Label.Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Label">
        <Setter Property="Label.Height" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="Panel.Margin" Value="0,0,25,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Label.Padding" Value="0"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Form">
        <Setter Property="Page.Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

I'm new to WPF and it probably shows. I can't get scrollbars to work like I want. For some reason, the vertical scrollbar *never appears* even if my window's height is less than the minimum height of the page whose XAML markup I've shown above.

I'm new to all of this, so if anyone can give me some advice on what I'm doing wrong or post helpful links to helpful resources, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The ScrollBar ought to work, check again.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. I run the app, I try to resize the window, but the scrollbar never appears, no matter how I resize it.

Comment: Then something else is interfering. Not enough info here to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've solved it by removing MinHeight from the Page. I still don't understand the point of those attributes (MinHeight/MinWidth) seeing as the window doesn't respect them and the scrollbar is completely disabled if added.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Grid layout instead

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>
```

The first and third column will take up as much space as needed, the second one will take up the rest.

As for the `Scrollbars`: That should actually work, could you add the XAML for your `Frame`?

Comment: I figured out I had to swap the second and third columns for the above to work. Don't want to use grid because adding rows in the front or middle becomes burdensome. I use a NavigationWindow for the first window, XAML in first post.